# How to create stored procedure to create views across databases in the same SQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to create a stored procedure in the master database that creates views across other databases under this.

I tried using "USE dbname" under EXEC, but it did not work.

This is the code I'm using,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE BuildMultipleViews
    AS
    EXEC ('USE database1
    GO
    CREATE VIEW ST
    AS
    SELECT DISTINCT t.col1, t.col2
 FROM table1 t')
GO
```

Comment: Use version of sp_MSforeachdb https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2201/making-a-more-reliable-and-flexible-spmsforeachdb/ by Aaron Bertrand.

Comment: @JohnDoe So, for each database that has a table named `table1`, create a view in that database, using the same view DDL for each? Please [edit] your question.

Answer (score 1):

`GO` is not a T-SQL statement. `GO` is a batch separator that's recognized only by T-SQL utilities like SSMS and SQLCMD and some SMO APIs. SQL Server will not understand the meaning of `GO` in the T-SQL script in your question.

To create views in databases other than the one of the invoking stored procedure, use `sp_executesql` qualified with the target database name and make sure the `CREATE VIEW` is the only statement in the executed batch:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.BuildMultipleViews
AS
DECLARE @CreateViewStatement nvarchar(MAX) = 
N'CREATE VIEW ST
AS
SELECT DISTINCT t.col1, t.col2
FROM table1 t;';
EXECUTE Database1..sp_executesql @CreateViewStatement;
EXECUTE Database2..sp_executesql @CreateViewStatement;
GO
```

Comment: The code is running successfully, but I do not see any views that are being created @Dan

Comment: @JohnDoe, perhaps you just need to refresh object explorer, or test with `SELECT * FROM Database1.dbo.ST;`.

Comment: @JohnDoe Does `Table1` table exists in other databases?

Comment: @JohnDoe, I tested the code and it does work. Make sure you are connected to the same SQL instance.

Comment: We are currently testing in just one database, but we aren't able to see the view in that database too.

Comment: @Sami Table1 does not exist in other databases.

Comment: @JohnDoe, you would get an error creating the view if the table didn't exist. Is your new proc *exactly* as in my answer?

Comment: CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.BuildMultipleViews
AS
DECLARE @CreateViewStatement nvarchar(MAX) = 
N'CREATE VIEW ST
AS
SELECT DISTINCT t.col1, t.col2
FROM table1 t;';
EXECUTE Database1..sp_executesql @CreateViewStatement;
GO

Database1 has the table, this the code im using.

Comment: @DanGuzman I think the OP want to pass the target database as a parameter, but this is not valid in `CREATE VIEW`

Comment: can we specify the destination where the view needs to be created as currently with the above-stored procedure? currently the view is getting created under the master database.@DanGuzman

Comment: @JohnDoe, I copy/pasted the code in your comment and the was successfully created in Database1. Have you verified you are running all on the same server (e.g. `SELECT @@SERVERNAME.`)?

Comment: @Sami, I don't see in the question or comments that the need is a parameterized database name. The code in my answer will not address such a need but the are other solutions that would.

Comment: @Dan  I was able to create the view in the expected database by using the statement EXECUTE Database1..sp_executesql @CreateViewStatement;
but we would want this to be picked up dynamically from the list of databases

Comment: @JohnDoe, there was no mention of that in your question and additional information is needed. Are you needing a proc to create the view in all user database on the instance? Only the one(s) specified via a parameter? Add those details to your question.